# Sliding window of mean across dataframe, based on alternate column in R

Tags: r, dataframe, mean, sliding-window

I am hoping to calculate the mean of a variable using a sliding window aproach but based on the values of another column in the dataframe. It is hard to explain so...

Take this example dataframe:

```
dist <- c(seq(1,100,by=1),seq(101,200,by=2))
value<- runif(150, min=0, max=10)

df <- as.data.frame(cbind(dist,value))
head(df)
```

I understand I can calculate a sliding window mean with the code below:

```
zoo::rollapply(df$value, width=50, by=25, FUN=mean, na.rm=TRUE,align="left")
```

However, this is not exactly what I want. I would like to calculate the `mean(df$value)` when `df$dist` ranges from `1-50` then `25-75` then `50-100` and so on.

The above does not do this as in my dataset I can not assume that `df$dist` counts systematically (i.e. does not miss out random numbers). Hence simply applying a window moving down a certain number of rows will produce an incorrect result.

Any advice on how I would approach this would be fantastic.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are several alternatives. (1) has no package dependencies, (2) uses rollapply and so is the most similar to the code in the question and (3) uses SQL and is the shortest code-wise.

**1) Base R** If the problem is that dist does not contain every number between 1 and its maximum value then we can iterate over the intervals like this:

```
Fun <- function(st, width, df, fun) {
  fun(subset(df, dist >= st & dist <= st + width - 1)$value)
}

width <- 50
step <- 25

starts <- seq(1, max(df$dist), step)

data.frame(starts, 
   ends = starts + width - 1,
   mean = sapply(starts, Fun, width, df, mean),
   N = sapply(starts, Fun, width, df, length))
```

giving:

```
  starts ends     mean  N
1      1   50 5.200910 50
2     26   75 4.710030 50
3     51  100 4.770270 50
4     76  125 4.880030 38
5    101  150 5.318415 25
6    126  175 5.575938 25
7    151  200 4.989383 25
8    176  225 3.918574 12
```

**2) rollapply** Another approach is to expand the input data frame in which case we can use rollapply.

```
library(zoo)

roll <- function(x, width, fun, step) {
  fun2 <- function(x) fun(na.omit(x))
  rollapply(x, width, by = step, fun2, partial = TRUE, align = "left")
}

width <- 50
step <- 25

m <- merge(df, data.frame(dist = 1:max(df$dist)), all = TRUE)
data.frame(starts, 
  ends = starts + width - 1,
  mean = roll(m$value, width, mean, step),
  N = roll(m$value, width, length, step)
)
```

giving:

```
  starts ends     mean  N
1      1   50 5.200910 50
2     26   75 4.710030 50
3     51  100 4.770270 50
4     76  125 4.880030 38
5    101  150 5.318415 25
6    126  175 5.575938 25
7    151  200 4.989383 25
8    176  225 3.918574 12
```

**3) sqldf** This can be formulated compactly using SQL with the indicated left join.

```
library(sqldf)

width <- 50
step <- 25

starts <- data.frame(starts = seq(1, max(df$dist), step))
fn$sqldf("select starts, starts+$width-1 ends, avg(value) mean, count(value) N
  from starts
  left join df on dist between starts and ends
  group by starts.rowid")
```

giving:

```
  starts ends     mean  N
1      1   50 5.200910 50
2     26   75 4.710030 50
3     51  100 4.770270 50
4     76  125 4.880030 38
5    101  150 5.318415 25
6    126  175 5.575938 25
7    151  200 4.989383 25
8    176  225 3.918574 12
```

### Note

For the input to be reproducible we must set the seed before using any random numbers so in the above we used this:

```
set.seed(123)
dist <- c(seq(1, 100, by = 1), seq(101, 200, by = 2))
value <- runif(150, min = 0, max = 10)
df <- data.frame(dist, value)
```

Comment: Thank you so much @G. Grothendieck this looks like exactly what I was after. Is there a way to also include `na.rm=T` within the `mean` function?
Looking at this script this would also work for multiple obseravtions at each distance? Thank you again

Comment: Also sorry for forgetting the `set.seed()`

Comment: I originally used na.rm = TRUE but then it seemed that since we were doing it for both mean and length it made more sense to factor it out.  You could provide a function(x) mean(x, na.rm = TRUE) and function(x) length(na.omit(x)) to roll and then use it directly rather than defining fun2 but that would expand the code.

Comment: Ok thank so you much for your very comprehensive and helpful answer. Upvoted and accepted - have a wonderful day!